# Aws cli: The filter condition returns all the running instance instead of those with a particular tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to able find out the ec2 machines that are running and tagged with a particular value.

I used the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=worker1 \
--filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=running
```

It basically returns all running instance of ec2 machines.

How can I make the aws cli to treat the filters as a combination of conditions? i.e. only active machines with name 'worker1'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=worker1" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running"
```

Don’t specify the `--filter` parameter twice. Surround each filter with quotes. Details and examples covering your use case are detailed here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html